# Помогите определиться с правильным паттерном для задания

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования

Состоит задача в использовании паттерна. Задача звучит примерно так.
Определить спецификацию класов для моделирования обьектов графического интерфейся пользователя(окна, кнопки, текстовые поля). Реализовать механизм реакции на события в любом с елементов.
Тоесть, как я понял нужно использовать паттерн который будет ловить например нажатие кнопки и передавать информацию о сделаном. Выбор между Observer и Mediator. Я думаю что Observer но проблема в том что тогда получаеться 3 субтекта и один наблюдатель, а ведь смысл паттерна в одном субьекте и нескольких наблюдателях или я ошибаюсь? Что можете посоветовать?

Comment: Один наблюдатель будет только при однотипном поведении всех трёх «субъектов». В противном случае наблюдателей будет несколько, по одному на каждый из «субъектов» наблюдения.

Comment: Composite + Observer. Почитайте о том, как это сделано в DOM